# How to increase ocean foam?

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, shaders, fluid-simulation, dynamic-paint

I created an ocean simulation in which a ship passes and displaces the ocean but the problem here is that the foam is not visible or less visible in camera view. How do I increase the foam cover area? P.S. I used dynamic paint.

Here's top render preview:
[image]

Notice how there's no or less foam visible in camera view:
[image]

Render:
[image]

Here's the node setup for ocean material:
[image]

Node setup for foam group:
[image]

.blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1riFsU5R0CJwAX7rgO9Jr1xss6Fsaeu4N/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add blend file

Comment: @Chris added .blend link

Comment: @Chris Also, you'll not find smoke because I rendered and composited it in a separate file.

Comment: Nobody is answering.

Comment: Fine, I'll do it myself...

Comment: in your uploaded file is no brush at all!? just canvas...

Comment: but if you can do it yourself, you should do it ;) By this you learn best!

Comment: Brush is there, under empty object named brush.001

Comment: Can you tell if the rendered image above is good?

Comment: ah...you disabled it in viewports...found it

Comment: It's definitely there otherwise there won't be any effect seen on the ocean but the effect is seen, well thanks...

Comment: The file must be heavy though? If it creates problem you can delete the hierarchy of Titanic object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127230/discussion-between-aman-kumar-and-chris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dumb didn't know much about using dynamic paint 2 months before but now I am a freaking expert. For those looking for answers, don't use a displace map instead use waves and use dynamic paint spread.